# produce same array in matlab and python with randn

Tags: python, matlab, random, random-seed

Hello I'm trying to produce the same vector in python and matlab but I'm not able to get it.
Someone knows how to do that?

My python code is:

```
np.random.seed(1337)
A = np.random.randn(1,3)
A = array([[-0.70318731, -0.49028236, -0.32181433]])
```

My matlab code is:

```
rng(1337, 'twister');
A = randn(1,3)
A = -0.7832   -0.7012   -0.7178
```

I would like to both give the same vector...

Comment: You could create the vector in one of the programs, save it to a file, and read it into the other.

Comment: Every compiler builds random function generator differently, so even if they are pseudo-random numbers the sequence will not be the same between matlab and python. I would probably generate the data in python and send the sequence over to matlab.

Comment: What's the point of creating the same set of random numbers? If it is for testing purposes to ensure you get the same result, then create a test method and plug in hardcoded values or read them from a file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both MATLAB and Python/NumPy, configured and used the way you do, use the same pseudo-random number generator. This generator produces the same sequence of numbers:

```matlab
>> format long
>> rng(1337, 'twister');
>> rand(1,3)
ans =
   0.262024675015582   0.158683972154466   0.278126519494360
```

```py
>>> np.random.seed(1337)
>>> np.random.rand(1,3)
array([[0.26202468, 0.15868397, 0.27812652]])
```

So it seems that it is the algorithm that produces normally distributed values from the random stream that is different. [There are many different algorithms to produce normally-distributed values from a random stream](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/%7Ewl/papers/07/csur07dt.pdf), and the MATLAB documentation doesn't mention which one it uses. [NumPy does mention at least one method](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/index.html):

> The Box-Muller method used to produce NumPy’s normals is no longer available in `Generator`. It is not possible to reproduce the exact random values using `Generator` for the normal distribution or any other distribution that relies on the normal such as the `RandomState.gamma` or `RandomState.standard_t`. If you require bitwise backward compatible streams, use `RandomState`.

In short, NumPy has a new system for random numbers (`Generator`), the legacy system is still available (`RandomState`). These two systems use a different algorithm for converting a random stream into normally distributed numbers:

```py
>>> r = np.random.RandomState(1337)
>>> r.randn(1,3)                        # same as np.random.randn()
array([[-0.70318731, -0.49028236, -0.32181433]])
>>> g = np.random.Generator(np.random.MT19937(1337))
>>> g.normal(size=(1,3))
array([[-1.22574554, -0.45908464,  0.77301878]])
```

`r` and `g` here both produce the same random stream (using the MT19937 generator with the same seed), but different normally distributed random numbers.

I cannot find which algorithm is used by `Generator.normal`.