Matching numpy rand ndarrays with MATLAB
I'm trying to match randomly generated ndarrays from numpy with MATLAB.
import numpy as np

# Set the seed for NumPy's random generator
np.random.seed(42) #Mersenne Twister is default
    
# Generate complex random numbers
a = 16
b = 4
c = 10
x_py = np.random.rand(a, b, c) + 1j * np.random.rand(a, b, c)

Here's the MATLAB version:
% Set the seed for MATLAB's random generator
rng(42, 'twister')  % Use the Mersenne Twister algorithm

% Generate complex random numbers
a = 16;
b = 4;
c = 10;
x_ml = rand([a, b, c], 'like', 1i);

Now, although the seed and generator type are matched, the states don't match, so I wasn't able to match x_py and x_ml.
I know the easier way is to generate in MATLAB, save to file and import in Python, but I want to understand the difference between the way the two APIs work and how they can be tweaked to get a matching output.

Possible duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18486241/comparing-matlab-and-numpy-code-that-uses-random-number-generation, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62546379/produce-same-array-in-matlab-and-python-with-randn, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70157083/how-do-i-reproduce-the-same-random-integer-array-in-matlab-and-python

For one thing, one is using C order and one is F. You should isolate the dtyoe and shape issues from obtaining the same generator

This question is very similar to this other one, but with the addition that here we're dealing with 3D arrays and complex numbers.
According to the other Q&A, MATLAB fills arrays column-wise while Python fills them row-wise. You need to transpose the result of the one to match the other. For 3D arrays, the indexing order in Python is [z,y,x], in MATLAB it is [y,x,z]. The storage order is reversed though, in MATLAB the y (first) index is the one that indexes contiguous memory addresses, whereas the x (last) index in Python does that. So we need to define the arrays with a different order for the sizes, and then permute the dimensions to make them match.
The other issue is that in Python, np.random.rand(a, b, c) + 1j * np.random.rand(a, b, c) first generates all real values, then all imaginary values. In MATLAB, rand([a, b, c], 'like', 1i) will generate a real value, then an imaginary one, then a real one, etc.
Putting it all together,
x_ml = permute(rand([c, b, a]) + 1j * rand([c, b, a]), [2,1,3])

produces the same array as x_py in the question.
